# How do I disable sound, in MSTSC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mstsc

I get a beep that sounds like a BIOS level, at VERY loud volume, when in an MSTSC session to a server.

Which when I am listening to some audio, is almost deafining in volume.  I often jump and curse at the volume of it!

Is there anyway to disable this?  There is no sound card on the Windows servers, and thus no volume to turn down.

Worst is that within the Active Directory Users and Computers snapins, if I have a Find window open, and click on the background ADUC, I get one of these beeps, and it HURTS!

Any hints on how to shut that beeping down?  (Same on deletes of users, and other actions).

Client is WinXP SP3, target is Win2K8 and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know OS you are using and accessing, but does this help? [Disable System Beep in Windows Vista](http://weyland.be/wrdprss/index.php/2007/02/08/disable-system-beep-in-windows-vista/)

Looks like there is a system device that controls that particular beep.

Comment: I am actually running WinXP SP3, connecting to a Win2K8 server, and that did the trick!

My ears thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: You are very welcome, I am sure I'll need the same trick eventually :)

Answer (score 4):

In MSTSC/Remote Desktop, before you connect, click Options, Local Resources. Then choose "Do Not Play" under Remote Computer Sound.

[image]

Comment: Just tried it, still did not work!  Do Not Play and still deafining beeps.

Comment: -1 because it did not work!  :)  Nah, I will take that back, since I thank you for the effort!

Comment: Also tried Leave at Remote Computer.  Still beeping.

Comment: Astonishingly, it is a service on MY machine, the Beep service that is at fault.  I never would have suspected that!  Always assumed it was the machine I was connecting too.

Answer (score 2):

disable for session:

```
net stop beep
```

disable for good:

```
sc config beep start= disabled
```

note this disables the beep service on your local machine!

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00838671.aspx) any good ?

Comment: I used the GUI approach suggested in the Accepted Answer, but I suspect that the options in this article are the same basic result, using more command line/registry approaches.

Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Geoffc.  Sign into your server.  Bring up Terminal Services Configuration.  Edit the RDP settings on it,  you can stop it from sending sound, clipboard, etc.

Disable sound.

if you still get it, disable sound in the bios!  See link below.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/73767bca-021b-480f-9001-fffaae2220da

Comment: Nope, in this case, the accepted answer was correct.  Doing what you suggest at least from the RDP issue did not help.   Since I will be connecting to stacks of servers, BIOS disabling is probably not an option.  But the Beep device was the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off remote computer sound during a session. After running remote desktop go to the options and under the "Local Resources" tab there is "Remove computer sound" set this to "Do not play".

Comment: As the nicer answer with the screen shot, it does not work!  Still beepity-beeping, and killing my ears!

Answer (score 0):

When you fire up MSTSC, before you connect to the remote box, click on Options --> Local Resources, and there is an option for "Remote Audio."  You can click on Settings and choose "Do not play" for Remote audio playback.

Comment: As the nicer answer with the screen shot, it does not work!  Still beepity-beeping, and killing my ears!